# x13 Arima analysis with negative values

Tags: arima

I'm running x13 Arima analysis on a US GDP series to get the "trend" component.

```
2008-12-31  -8.2
2009-03-31  -5.4
2009-06-30  -0.5
2009-09-30  1.3
2009-12-31  3.9
2010-03-31  1.7
2010-06-30  3.9
2010-09-30  2.7
2010-12-31  2.5
2011-03-31  -1.5
2011-06-30  2.9
2011-09-30  0.8
```

As you can see the data has negative values and when trying to run the model on the data it complains:

> X13Error: WARNING: Automatic transformation selection cannot be done
>   on a
>             series with zero or negative values.

What is the right way to run X13 when you have negative values in your series?

(This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000059/statsmodels-x13error-warning-automatic-transformation-selection-cannot-be-do where I asked about the program settings)

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I think you are right. Is there a way to move it?

Comment: Flag it, maybe?